# How to use addOLEObject function to open a file for Read-Only?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a button [DisplayChart] in a PPT slide that embeds an Excel chart onto a slide using AddOLEObject.

```
Set shapeOnPPT = 
ActivePresentation.Slides.FindBySlideID(mySlideID).Shapes.AddOLEObject(Left:=100,_
Top:=100, Width:=500, Height:=400, FileName:="c:\ThisDoc\Tester123.xlsx", Link:=msoTrue)
```

**Problem**

When I go into presenter view and click the [DisplayButton] and `Tester123.xlsx` is opened by another user, the PPT would 'hang'. A ctrl-alt-del reveals an Excel app has opened with this prompt message:

[image]

Clicking Read-Only or Notify closes the Excel app and PPT would not hang anymore.

**What I've tried**

I figured that I need to open `testing.xlsx` as Read-Only automatically. According to [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff745501.aspx), it seems like I can use the
*Link* parameter.

> Determines whether the OLE object will be linked to the file from which it was created. If you specified a value for ClassName, this argument must be msoFalse.

However, changing this parameter to `msoTrue` or `msoFalse` still does not solve anything.

P.s. In Windows 7, this problem does not occur. I'm currently using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there is no parameter/function that allows us to do this when adding OLE objects. The closest possible thing is to use the [`SetAttr` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a5wx7516%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to set the file to Read-Only before opening it. This allows multiple programs to **view** the content of the file.

e.g.

```
SetAttr "c:\ThisDoc\Tester123.xlsx", vbReadOnly
Set shapeOnPPT = 
ActivePresentation.Slides.FindBySlideID(mySlideID).Shapes.AddOLEObject(Left:=100,_
Top:=100, Width:=500, Height:=400, FileName:="c:\ThisDoc\Tester123.xlsx", Link:=msoTrue)
SetAttr "c:\ThisDoc\Tester123.xlsx", vbNormal
```

NOTE : Remember to set it to `vbNormal` after you have run the function or else there might be issues when other programs try to access the file.

Also, a significant risk is if your application crashes while `.addOLEObject` is running, the file will still be in Read-Only state and you would have to manually change it back.

Answer (score 0):

haven't been able to test it but you can try this

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = false   
Set shapeOnPPT = 
ActivePresentation.Slides.FindBySlideID(mySlideID).Shapes.AddOLEObject(Left:=100,_
Top:=100, Width:=500, Height:=400, FileName:="c:\ThisDoc\Tester123.xlsx", Link:=msoTrue)    
Application.DisplayAlerts = true
```

Comment: Does not work... I don't need the displayalerts to be hidden... I just need to open the `.xlsx` file as read-only programmatically.

Comment: may be you can try approch of   Application.SendKeys("~")